# How to load complex data via web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Well I have model with 2 objects:
Project and Words with many to many relationship.

```
public class Project
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public List<ProjectWord> ProjectWords { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectWord
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("Project"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public int project_Id { get; set; }
        [Key, ForeignKey("Word"), Column(Order = 1)]
        public int word_Id { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
        public Word Word { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
public class Word
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string WordContent { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectWord> ProjectWords { get; set; }       
    }
```

I'm using webapi 2 and EF 6

my controller's get is:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Project))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProject(int id)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

            if (project == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(project);
        }
```

well when I call this it returns me project entity but it's ProjectWords is always null. ( I have data in database).

Tried to disable lazy loading in my context constructor

```
public KwToolsServerContext() : base("name=KwToolsServerContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
```

but nothing helps.

Can somebody point me into right direction?

Comment: Have you tried eagerly loading the entities?  So something like `db.Projects.Include(x => x.ProjectWords).Where(x => x.Id == id)`

Comment: thanks it is good, but in this case in project words I have Word always null. Can you please point me how to include also Words with this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried eagerly loading the entities? So something like:

```
 db.Projects
   .Include(x => x.ProjectWords)
   .Include(x => x.ProjectWords.Select(y => y.Word))
   .Where(x => x.Id == id)
```